# Copy Name from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, rename

I have two separate sheets, let's call them Data and Duplicate. They both have their own set of tabs. Each tab has its own set of data.
I want the name of the sheet "Data" to rename the first tab in Duplicate sheet tab1.

How can this be done using app script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in spreadsheet Data

```
function renamefirst() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id of spreadsheet Duplicate");
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.setName("Tab1")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
May I ask a fallow up question?
What if the name of the sheet changes since it is named with the current date and year, id it possible to code an app script that will update the new name everytime a new entry is created.